# IPC on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ipc, fork, pipe

I'm trying to use IPC Unix mechanisms (pipes, shared memory, sockets) into Visual Studio IDE (still using C and C++ files), but I'm finding it hard to know which header files I should include in order to work with, let's say for example, a fork() command, or similar.

I've tried googling it but I didn't have any luck.

Thank you very much!

Silvio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [winsock.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740632%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for sockets.  Shared memory can be done with memory-mapped files.  [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20shared%20memory) "[windows shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" gives several relevant results.  Pipes are supported, search MSDN for "[pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365780%28VS.85%29.aspx)" and the ['CreatePipe' function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365781%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Fork is not supported - there are some [hacks](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32040421/ntcreateprocess-and-fork.aspx) but they are not particularly easy/efficient.  Probably better to redesign to avoid requiring fork.

Comment: thnks! I've just found out that for Windows you have CreateProcess in include.h, which is an equivalent windows systemCall to Unix Fork.

Comment: `CreateProcess` is similar to, but not equivalent to `fork`. See http://www.gamedev.net/topic/360290-fork-on-windows/ for a discussion of the differences.